# Insert list of vectors in matrix by matching names in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large list of vectors with names and values. The values of the vectors need to be added to the matrix by matching the names of vector in the list with the column names of matrix.

For example, the list of vectors and matrix is as follows:

```r
## list
vec1 <- c(1.0, 3.3, 5.5)
names(vec1) <- c("v1", "v3", "v5")
vec2 <- c(2.0, 1.3, 5.0)
names(vec2) <- c("v3", "v5", "v10")
list_vec <- list(vec1, vec2)

## matrix
mat0 <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 100) 
colnames(mat0) <- paste("v", 1:ncol(mat0), sep = "")
```

The output should be the `vec1` in the first row of the matrix and `vec2` in the second row of matrix.

Comment: try `mat0[1,names(vec1)] <- vec1` and `mat0[2,names(vec2)] <- vec2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `base` package of `R`, maybe the following can help:

```
r <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(length(list_vec)), function(k) {mat0[k,names(list_vec[[k]])] <- list_vec[[k]]; mat0[k,]}))
```

or

```
r <- rbind(t(sapply(seq(length(list_vec)), function(k) {mat0[k,names(list_vec[[k]])] <- list_vec[[k]]; mat0[k,]})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Reduce()` in base and `dplyr::bind_rows()`:

```
library(dplyr)
mat <- Reduce(bind_rows, list_vec)
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
mat

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#      v1    v3    v5   v10
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   3.3   5.5     0
# 2     0   2     1.3     5
```

Note: Don't use `rbind()` in base because it doesn't consider the matching of vector names.

Comment: Awesome. This was very easy step . Just i may need to remove the NAs later. Thank you.

Comment: @AbhijeetPatil sorry for neglecting that. I edit my answer to make the NAs 0.